# RTABMAP not working with Kinect+Odometry

Tags: slam, navigation, rtabmap-ros, rtabmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to use RTAB-MAP with an AGV with a kinnects (Xtion asus pro live) added on top. The system have two computers: 1- (roscore) AGV computer (publishing the odometry, laser scanner, etc..). 2- (where I am running RTAB-map) Computer with kinect.

However, when I launch rtabmap (kinect+odometry), nothing appears. (launching only the kinect works fine).

This is my roslaunch file (including static_tf from base_link to camera_link which is not provided by the AGV):

```
<launch>
    <!-- TF static transform base_link to camera_link -->
    <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="link1_broadcaster" args="0 0 1.5 0 0 0 /base_link /camera_link 100" />


    <group ns="rtabmap">

    <node name="rtabmap" pkg="rtabmap_ros" type="rtabmap" output="screen" args="--delete_db_on_start">

        <param name="frame_id" type="string" value="base_link"/>
        <param name="subscribe_depth" type="bool" value="true"/>

        <remap from="odom" to="/odom_comb"/>
        <remap from="rgb/image" to="/camera/rgb/image_rect_color"/>
        <remap from="depth/image" to="/camera/depth_registered/image_raw"/>
        <remap from="rgb/camera_info" to="/camera/rgb/camera_info"/>

        <param name="queue_size" type="int" value="10"/>

        <!-- RTAB-Map's parameters -->


        <param name="RGBD/AngularUpdate" type="string" value="0.01"/>
        <param name="RGBD/LinearUpdate" type="string" value="0.01"/>
        <param name="Rtabmap/TimeThr" type="string" value="700"/>
        <param name="Mem/RehearsalSimilarity" type="string" value="0.45"/>
        <param name="RGBD/OptimizeFromGraphEnd" type="string" value="true"/>

    </node>
    </group>


    <!-- Visualisation RTAB-Map -->
    <node pkg="rtabmap_ros" type="rtabmapviz" name="rtabmapviz"  output="screen">
        <param name="subscribe_depth"     type="bool"   value="true"/>
        <param name="subscribe_laserScan"      type="bool"   value="false"/>
        <param name="subscribe_odom_info" type="bool"   value="false"/>
        <param name="frame_id"            type="string" value="base_link"/>

        <remap from="rgb/image" to="/camera/rgb/image_rect_color"/>
        <remap from="depth/image" to="/camera/depth_registered/image_raw"/>
        <remap from="rgb/camera_info" to="/camera/rgb/camera_info"/>

    </node>

</launch>
```

I suspect that the problem is on the TF tree due to publishing transforms from 2 different computers. The tf tree (without unning RTABMAP) can be seen here:
[agv+static_pub+rtabmap](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4-7tdI3JhO9dHJaN2Rsem9FNVk/view?usp=sharing) (I cannot attach pictures due to not having enough points on this forum).

Also, the output from roswtf is:

*

```
WARNING The following node subscriptions are unconnected: 
    * /SerialProxy:
    * /serial0_rx
    * /web_map_generator:
    * /move_base_node/local_costmap/inflated_obstacles
 * /supervisor:
   * /move_base_node/MIRPlannerROS/len_to_goal
 * /rtabmap/rtabmap:
   * /tf_static
   * /rtabmap/move_base/feedback
   * /rtabmap/move_base/status
   * /rtabmap/goal
   * /rtabmap/goal_node
   * /rtabmap/move_base/result
 * /mirEventTrigger:
   * /event_cmd
 * /rtabmapviz:
   * /goal_reached
   * /goal_node
   * /odom
   * /mapData
   * /tf_static
   * /global_path
   * /info
WARNING The following nodes are unexpectedly connected:
 * /laser_back/driver->/roswtf_12815_1452249335691 (/tf)
 * /mirSound->/bridge (/rosout)
 * /laser_front/driver->/roswtf_12815_1452249335691 (/tf)
 * unknown (http://192.168.12.20:40313/)->/mirSound (/mir_sound)
 * unknown (http://192.168.12.20:50779/)->/mirSound (/mir_sound)
 * /bridge->/bridge (/rosout)
 * unknown (http://192.168.12.20:59477/)->/mirSound (/mir_sound)
 * /bridge_api->/bridge (/rosout)
 * /rtabmap/rtabmap->/roswtf_12815_1452249335691 (/tf)
WARNING These nodes have died:
 * mir_param_publisher-1
WARNING Received out-of-date/future transforms:
 * receiving transform from [/StateTF] that differed from ROS time by 28611.7888631s
 * receiving transform from [/transform_footprint] that differed from ROS time by 28611.7991738s
 * receiving transform from [/laser_back/transform] that differed from ROS time by 28611.7992606s
 * receiving transform from [/transform_imu] that differed from ROS time by 28611.7991301s
 * receiving transform from [/mir_amcl] that differed from ROS time by 28611.984325s
 * receiving transform from [/laser_front/transform] that differed from ROS time by 28611.7992704s
```

- 

Is it possible that the problem is due to this huge TF delays from the AGV related transforms?  What could I do to solve it?

(p.d: this is the [output](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4-7tdI3JhO9N1FEbFJxY05kaUU/view?usp=sharing) from the roslaunch:

```
isaac@isaac-Latitude-E6540 ~/Desktop/unblocking_rtab $ roslaunch kinnect_odometry.launch 
... logging to /home/isaac/.ros/log/3f40f5f4-b61b-11e5-93bb-83cec338a840/roslaunch-isaac-Latitude-E6540-10936.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://isaac-Latitude-E6540:37077/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro: indigo
 * /rosversion: 1.11.16
 * /rtabmap/rtabmap/Mem/RehearsalSimilarity: 0.45
 * /rtabmap/rtabmap/RGBD/AngularUpdate: 0.01
 * /rtabmap/rtabmap/RGBD/LinearUpdate: 0.01
 * /rtabmap/rtabmap/RGBD/OptimizeFromGraphEnd: true
 * /rtabmap/rtabmap/Rtabmap/TimeThr: 700
 * /rtabmap/rtabmap/frame_id: base_link
 * /rtabmap/rtabmap/queue_size: 10
 * /rtabmap/rtabmap/subscribe_depth: True
 * /rtabmapviz/frame_id: base_link
 * /rtabmapviz/subscribe_depth: True
 * /rtabmapviz/subscribe_laserScan: False
 * /rtabmapviz/subscribe_odom_info: False

NODES
  /rtabmap/
    rtabmap (rtabmap_ros/rtabmap)
  /
    link1_broadcaster (tf/static_transform_publisher)
    rtabmapviz (rtabmap_ros/rtabmapviz)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.12.20:11311

core service [/rosout] found
process[link1_broadcaster-1]: started with pid [10945]
process[rtabmap/rtabmap-2]: started with pid [10946]
process[rtabmapviz-3]: started with pid [10950]
[ INFO] [1452248271.823447177]: Starting node...
[ INFO] [1452248271.858289290]: Starting node...
[ INFO] [1452248271.955024955]: rtabmapviz: Using configuration from "/home/isaac/.ros/rtabmapGUI.ini"
[ INFO] [1452248272.031309782]: rtabmap: frame_id = base_link
[ INFO] [1452248272.031363336]: rtabmap: map_frame_id = map
[ INFO] [1452248272.031383702]: rtabmap: queue_size = 10
[ INFO] [1452248272.031405005]: rtabmap: tf_delay = 0.050000
[ INFO] [1452248272.031425694]: rtabmap: depth_cameras = 1
[ INFO] [1452248272.664404485]: Reading parameters from the ROS server...
[ INFO] [1452248272.878213850]: Setting RTAB-Map parameter "Mem/RehearsalSimilarity"="0.45"
[ INFO] [1452248273.085919415]: Parameters read = 0
[ INFO] [1452248273.338840271]: Setting RTAB-Map parameter "RGBD/AngularUpdate"="0.01"
[ INFO] [1452248273.356835074]: 
/rtabmapviz subscribed to:
   /camera/rgb/image_rect_color,
   /camera/depth_registered/image_raw,
   /camera/rgb/camera_info,
   /odom
[ INFO] [1452248273.365194412]: Setting RTAB-Map parameter "RGBD/LinearUpdate"="0.01"
[ INFO] [1452248273.422709134]: rtabmapviz started.
[ INFO] [1452248273.465536891]: Setting RTAB-Map parameter "RGBD/OptimizeFromGraphEnd"="true"
[ INFO] [1452248273.721767461]: Setting RTAB-Map parameter "Rtabmap/TimeThr"="700"
[ INFO] [1452248274.500014304]: RTAB-Map rate detection = 1.000000 Hz
[ INFO] [1452248274.500153014]: rtabmap: Deleted database "/home/isaac/.ros/rtabmap.db" (--delete_db_on_start is set).
[ INFO] [1452248274.500178125]: rtabmap: Using database from "/home/isaac/.ros/rtabmap.db".
[ INFO] [1452248274.647943449]: rtabmap: Database version = "0.10.10".
[ INFO] [1452248274.928178272]: Registering Depth callback...
[ INFO] [1452248274.929296254]: 
/rtabmap/rtabmap subscribed to:
   /camera/rgb/image_rect_color,
   /camera/depth_registered/image_raw,
   /camera/rgb/camera_info,
   /odom_comb
[ INFO] [1452248274.929421499]: rtabmap 0.10.10 started...
```

Thanks a lot.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223684/rtabmap-not-working-with-kinect+odometry/) by [maik_mico](https://answers.ros.org/users/25505/maik_mico/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-01-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [maik_mico](https://answers.ros.org/users/25505/maik_mico/) on 2016-01-09**:
I updated the links to the goggle drive files (I realized that people could not see them).
Sorry for any inconvenience

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-01-09**:
Please include all the relevant (console) output in your question proper. If the google drive links ever go dead, this question (and any potential answers) will become useless.

**Comment by [maik_mico](https://answers.ros.org/users/25505/maik_mico/) on 2016-01-11**:
I have modified the original message including the relevant console output, roslaunch, etc.. The only thing I could not upload yet is a picture with the tf tree..

**Comment by [maik_mico](https://answers.ros.org/users/25505/maik_mico/) on 2016-01-11**:
Hi Mathieu,

I am receiving the topics correctly (odom_comb topic 40hz, camera topics 30hz). However rtabmap is not outputing anything on the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does /odom_comb have a timestamp set in the topic header? Or maybe the clocks from the computers are not synchronized. In roswtf above, you have a warning about out-of-data transforms with a delay of 28611.7888631s. You can compare the topic stamps with: `$rostopic echo /odom_comb/header/stamp`

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2016-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [maik_mico](https://answers.ros.org/users/25505/maik_mico/) on 2016-01-11**:
Problem solved. I had the same suspicion about Time stamps difference. It was in the order of more than 20000secs. So I created a node that subscribes and publishes the relevant transforms and odom_comb with new names and the local machine time stamp and everything works

**Comment by [maik_mico](https://answers.ros.org/users/25505/maik_mico/) on 2016-01-11**:
Thank you very much Mathieu. Should I document the solution and writte it on this post so it is also useful for other users? Or I just mark the previous message saying that its solved?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-01-11**:
@maik_mico: if possible, just synchronise the time of the involved PCs. Use something like `chrony` or `ntp`. No need to write custom nodes.

**Comment by [maik_mico](https://answers.ros.org/users/25505/maik_mico/) on 2016-01-11**:
I agree that would be the most optimum solution.. However I cannot access the computer from the AGV so I can only build things on top of it from a separate computer.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-01-11**:
So you can install and run ROS on the AGV computer, but can't change its time? What make and model are we talking about?

**Comment by [maik_mico](https://answers.ros.org/users/25505/maik_mico/) on 2016-01-11**:
Not exactly. The AGV it's developed under ROS but I cannot login to it's computer, so I just connected my computer to the same network and did an export ROS_MASTER_URI... Thus, I can access all its topics but cannot modify anything from its software. P.d: the AGV it's the MiR100

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-01-11**:
Well, you could always see whether the AGV is already running an NTP or Chrony server. Or, alternatively, you could set the clock of your addon PC to match the clock on the AGV.

In any case, perhaps just [contact](http://mobile-industrial-robots.com/en/contact/) them and ask?

**Comment by [maik_mico](https://answers.ros.org/users/25505/maik_mico/) on 2016-01-11**:
I will ask them if they are running NTP or Chrony. Thanks for the tip

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-01-11**:
You could just run an `nmap IP_OF_AGV` and see what comes out.